# Connection attempt failed because party did not respond error in ASP.Net anyone  know how to fix it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Whenever I run my service it never responds, I know it isn't the service as I have one similar running in a different aspx file running. I've looked into it and it's something to do with the web.config file but I don't know where. I was given a small web config file however when you put it in the place it says it doesn't like one specific line of coding in it.

This is the error I am getting:

> Server Error in '/webroot' Application.
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 195.195.43.253:880
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 195.195.43.253:880
>
> Source Error:
>   Line 29:         `Response.Write(sortcode & " " & accountnumber & " " & selectcase)`
>   Line 30:
>   Line 31:         `screen.Text = balance.CheckBalance(accountnumber)`
>   Line 32:     `End Sub`
>   Line 33:
>
> Source File: H:\webroot\menu.aspx    Line: 31
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did >not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because >connected host has failed to respond 195.195.43.253:880]
>     System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress >socketAddress) +239
>     System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) +35
>     System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, >Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult >asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +224
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>     System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) +1872945
>     System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() +13
>     System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, >Object[] parameters) +103
>     test.HSBC.CheckBalance(Int64 accountnumber) +72
>     ASP.menu_aspx.checkbalance(Object sender, EventArgs e) in H:\webroot\menu.aspx:31
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(St>ring eventArgument) +10
>     System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String >eventArgument) +13
>     System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
>     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean >includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET >Version:2.0.50727.5420

This is the asmx file:

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace = "HSBC" %>

<script runat="server">

    'Page Load
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim sortcode As String = CType(Session.Item("sessionsortnum"), String)
        Dim accountnumber As String = CType(Session.Item("sessionaccount"), String)
        Dim selectcase As String = CType(Session.Item("sessioncase"), String)

        testsort.Text = sortcode
        testbank.Text = accountnumber
        testselectc.Text = selectcase

    End Sub

    'Check Balance
    Private Sub checkbalance(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim balance As New test.HSBC()
        Dim sortcode As String = CType(Session.Item("sessionsortnum"), String)
        Dim accountnumber As String = CType(Session.Item("sessionaccount"), String)
        Dim selectcase As String = CType(Session.Item("sessioncase"), String)
        testsort.Text = sortcode
        testbank.Text = accountnumber
        testselectc.Text = selectcase

        Response.Write(sortcode & " " & accountnumber & " " & selectcase)

        screen.Text = balance.CheckBalance(accountnumber)
    End Sub

    Private Sub withdraw(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        'Session("moneyamount") = amountchoice.Text

        Dim balance As New test.HSBC()
        Dim sortcode As String = CType(Session.Item("sessionsortnum"), String)
        Dim accountnumber As String = CType(Session.Item("sessionaccount"), String)
        Dim selectcase As String = CType(Session.Item("sessioncase"), String)
        Dim amount As String = CType(Session.Item("moneyamount"), String)

        testsort.Text = sortcode
        testbank.Text = accountnumber
        testselectc.Text = selectcase

        Response.Write(sortcode & " " & accountnumber & " " & selectcase & " " & amount)

        screen.Text = balance.Withdraw(accountnumber, amount)

    End Sub
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Welcome to HSBC</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" style="top: 15px; left: 10px; position: absolute; height: 225px; width: 200px">
    </asp:Panel>


    <br />
    <br />
    <br />


           <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="490px" Width="1024px" style="top: 17px; left: 10px; position: absolute">

                        <%-- Onclick is to put the numbers into the textbox --%>
                        <asp:button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="1" width= "334px" height= "118px" style="top: 249px; left: 15px; position: absolute"  />
                        <asp:button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="2" width= "334px" height= "118px" style="top: 249px; left: 355px; position: absolute" />
                        <asp:button ID="btn3" runat="server" Text="3" height= "118px" style="top: 249px; left: 694px; position: absolute; width: 328px;"   />
                        <asp:button ID="btn4" runat="server" Text="4" width= "334px" height= "118px" style="top: 372px; left: 15px; position: absolute; right: 1021px;" />
                        <asp:button ID="btn5" runat="server" Text="5" width= "334px" height= "118px" style="top: 372px; left: 355px; position: absolute" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btn6" runat="server" Text="6" height="118px" style="top: 372px; left: 695px; position: absolute; width: 327px;" />
                        <asp:button ID="btn7" runat="server" Text="7" width= "334px" height= "118px" style="top: 495px; left: 15px; position: absolute" />
                        <asp:button ID="btn8" runat="server" Text="8" width= "334px" height= "118px" style="top: 495px; left: 356px; position: absolute"  />
                        <asp:Button ID="btn9" runat="server" Text="9" height="118px" style="top: 495px; left: 694px; position: absolute; width: 329px;" />
                        <asp:button ID="btn0" runat="server" Text="0" width= "334px" height= "118px" style="top: 618px; left: 356px; position: absolute" />

                            <%-- Points to Visa Web Service to use their services --%>
                            <asp:button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Enter" height= "118px" style="top: 618px; left: 695px; position: absolute; width: 327px;" />

                            <%-- Clears the text box --%>
                            <asp:Button ID="cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel/Clear" height="118px" style="top: 618px; left: 15px; position: absolute"  width="334px" />

                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" style="top: 1px; left: 827px; position: absolute; height: 221px; width: 196px">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" 
                                style="width: 195px; height: 46px; top: 1px; left: -210px; position: absolute" 
                                Text="Check Balance" onclick="checkbalance" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" 
                                style="width: 195px; height: 46px; top: 61px; left: -200px; position: absolute" 
                                Text="Withdraw Cash" onclick="withdraw" />

                        </asp:Panel>

                        <asp:Label ID="lblBalance" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="screen" runat="server" 

                            style="width: 383px; height: 214px; top: 8px; left: 221px; position: absolute"></asp:TextBox>
             </asp:Panel>
         &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="testbank" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="testsort" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="testselectc" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            </form>
         </body>
</html>
```

The error tells me it's on the actual call part `screen.Text = balance.Withdraw(accountnumber, amount)`. I know it is working as I've commented it out had it writing what is in the variables to the screen.

This is what is in the asmx file

```
  <%@ WebService Language="vb" Class="HSBC" %>
Imports System
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

'Imports everything that is needed ready to use within the web services

<WebService(Namespace:="http://heweb.grimsby.ac.uk/s0082708/")> Public Class HSBC

    'Public to allow access


    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Public AuthSoapHd As New AuthenticationHeader

    'Inherits the imports to use in the web service

    Public Auth As New AuthenticationHeader

    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '                                                   Unsecure Balance Call
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    <WebMethod()> Public Function CheckBalance(ByVal accountnumber As Long) As String
        Return CheckBal(accountnumber)       
    End Function


    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '                                                   Check Balance Call - Secure (SOAP HEADER AUTH)
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    '<WebMethod(), SoapHeader("Auth")> Public Function AuthCheckBalance(ByVal accountnumber As Long) As String
    '   If (Auth.username = "HSBC" And Auth.password = "HSBC") Then
    '      Return CheckBal(accountnumber)
    ' Else
    '    Throw New Exception("Did not manage to login")
    ' End If

    'End Function

    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '                                   Check Balance function
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    'Creates a service web method

    Private Function CheckBal(ByVal accountnumber As Long) As String

        Dim account As String = CType(Session.Item("sessionaccount"), String)

        'Database drivers, connections and commands
        Dim BalanceDr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim BalanceConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim BalanceCmd As OleDbCommand

        'Database connection string
        Dim Connx As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("../database/HSBC.mdb") & ";"

        'SQL

        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT Transaction_Amount FROM Transaction WHERE Account_Number = " & _
        account

        Dim bal As String

        'Open the connection to the database
        BalanceConn = New OleDbConnection(Connx)
        BalanceCmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, BalanceConn)
        BalanceConn.Open()

        'Create a DataReader that will return information.
        BalanceDr = _
        BalanceCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        If BalanceDr.Read() Then
            'A row was returned
            bal = BalanceDr(0)
        Else
            'A row was not returned
            bal = "No Name Found"
        End If

        BalanceDr.Close()
        Return bal
    End Function
End Class
```

And this is the web config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        Web references sit here
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>

        <compilation debug="false">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what is causing it to fail connection?

Answer (score 0):

It was redirecting wrong in the web config.

http://www.example.com:808/example

Deleted the 808 in the address like all the others without the 808 and it seems to be working fine as it complained about the virtual directly, it was running from usb stick, so it seems to be working now. So if anyone else has this problem check the web ref part of your web.config as it could be that.